# Аннотации JAX-RS

Tags: java, jersey, аннотации, jax-rs

Всем привет! Данный код взят как пример с Jersey Guide. Я решил задать пару    вопросов для того чтобы в нём разобраться.

```
// Example 3.23. Injection

@Path("{id:\\d+}")
public class InjectedResource {

    // Injection onto field
    @DefaultValue("q")
    @QueryParam("p")
    private String p;

    // Injection onto constructor parameter
    public InjectedResource(@PathParam("id") int id) { ... }

    // Injection onto resource method parameter
    @GET
    public String get(@Context UriInfo ui) { ... }

    // Injection onto sub-resource resource method parameter
    @Path("sub-id")
    @GET
    public String get(@PathParam("sub-id") String id) { ... }

    // Injection onto sub-resource locator method parameter
    @Path("sub-id")
    public SubResource getSubResource(@PathParam("sub-id") String id) { ... }

    // Injection using bean setter method
    @HeaderParam("X-header")
    public void setHeader(String header) { ... }
 }
```

1. Не понятна синтаксическая запись данной строки:

   ```
   @Path("{id:\\d+}")
   ```

   Насколько я знаю, передаётся в {Сам параметр: id, name , last name, etc..}
    Запись `{id:\\d+}` непонятна, и я буду рад если кто сможет объяснить.
2. Значение `@DefaultValue` в данном примере переменная `p` по дефолту равна `"q"`?
3. Возле этой переменной  `@QueryParam("p")`как понимать такую запись, зачем над полем две аннотации ?
4. Данная запись понятна `public InjectedResource(@PathParam("id") int id)`,
   к переменной `id` прикрепляется `id`.
5. Данная запись непонятна `public String get(@Context UriInfo ui)`,

   Механизм `@Context` - зачем используется данная аннотация? Из документации не нашел для себя нечего полезного.
6. Следующий код вроде бы содержит два метода, которые делают то же самое: 
   первый достаёт ресурсы и второй, на одном аннотация Get, на другом - нет. Какая между ними разница ?

   ```
   // Injection onto sub-resource resource method parameter
   @Path("sub-id")
   @GET
   public String get(@PathParam("sub-id") String id) { ... }

   // Injection onto sub-resource locator method parameter
   @Path("sub-id")
   public SubResource getSubResource(@PathParam("sub-id") String id) { ... }
   ```
7. Во втором примере не понятно предназначение этого метода:

   ```
   @Context
   public void setRequest(Request request) {
       // injection into a setter method
       System.out.println(request != null);
   }
   ```
8. Каково отличие `@Context`, `@QueryParam`, `@PathParam` между собой ? 
   Может быть для некоторых вопросы банальные и простые, но я как новичок с Jersey  не понимаю разницу в предназначении.

   ```
   // Example 3.26. Example of possible injections:
   // https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2789

   @Path("resource")
   public static class SummaryOfInjectionsResource {
       @QueryParam("query")
       String param; // injection into a class field

       @GET    
       public String get(@QueryParam("query") String methodQueryParam) {
           // injection into a resource method parameter
           return "query param: " + param;
       }

       @Path("sub-resource-locator")
       public Class<SubResource> subResourceLocator(@QueryParam("query") String subResourceQueryParam) {
           // injection into a sub resource locator parameter
           return SubResource.class;
       }

       public SummaryOfInjectionsResource(@QueryParam("query") String constructorQueryParam) {
           // injection into a constructor parameter
       }

       @Context
       public void setRequest(Request request) {
           // injection into a setter method
           System.out.println(request != null);
       }
   }

   public static class SubResource {
       @GET
       public String get() {
           return "sub resource";
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Вы свалили кучу вопросов с просьбой разжевать документацию в один. Это плохая практика.

Comment: Понятно. Новичок на сервере буду знать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала, раз не понятна документация конкретной реализации JAX-RS (Jersey), стоит прочитать [спецификацию JAX-RS](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-edr3-spec/jaxrs-2_0-edr3-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1463044700_36900c2edeebb74939d4c802850d0959), в которой все истолковано максимально подробно и недвусмысленно.

1. Аннотация [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) задает шаблон пути для ресурса. В данном случае путь состоит из единственного параметра шаблона с именем `id`, который должен удовлетворять регулярному выражению `\\d+` (что соответствует целому числу произвольной длины).

   Пример:

   - путь `/1234` - удовлетворяет шаблону, параметру id будет соответствовать значение `1234`;
   - путь `/abc123` - не удовлетворяет шаблону, методы данного класса не будут вызываться по этому пути.

   В дальнейшем параметр шаблона пути `id` можно будет связать с аргументом любого метода аннотацией [`@PathParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html).

---

2. Да, аннотация [`@DefaultValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) задает значение по-умолчанию, если оно не было получено благодаря другим аннотациям JAX-RS (`PathParam`, `QueryParam`, `MatrixParam`, `CookieParam`, `FormParam`, или `HeaderParam`).

---

3. Аннотация [`@QueryParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html)`("p")`над полем `private String p` привязывает URL-параметр (тот, что идет в URL после знака `?`) с именем `p` к этому полю. Если параметр `p` в URL отсутствует, будет использоваться значение из аннотации [`@DefaultValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html)

   Пример:

   - Для запроса по адресу `/12345?p=abc` значение поля `p` будет равно `"abc"`.
   - Для запроса по адресу `/12345` значение поля `p` будет равно `"q"`.

---

4. Да, см. пункт 1.

---

5. Аннотация [`@Context`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) внедряет значения различных метаданных текущего запроса, ориентируясь по типу аргумента или поля. Тому, какие метаданные можно внедрять посвящена глава 9 спецификации:

   - [`UriInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) - шаблон пути запроса
   - [`HttpHeaders`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html) - заголовки запроса
   - [`Request`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Request.html) - предусловия запроса
   - [`SecurityContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) - данные авторизации/аутентификации
   - [`Providers`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers.html) - расширения JAX-RS

   В конкретно вашем случае в аргумент метода будет внедрены метаданные о шаблоне пути ([`UriInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html)) текущего запроса.

---

6. Смотрите внимательнее: в одном случае возвращается `String`, в другом - `SubResource`. Т.к. в первом случае есть аннотация `@GET`, то соответствующие запросы будут обработаны методом. Во втором случае, нет аннотации, описывающей конкретный HTTP-метод, поэтому Jersey будет рассматривать возвращаемый экземпляр `SubResource` как еще один ресурс JAX-RS и искать в нем аннотации.

---

7. См. пункт 5.

---

8. См. пункты 1, 3, 5. Как я упоминал, еще бывают: [`MatrixParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/MatrixParam.html), [`CookieParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/CookieParam.html), [`FormParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html), или [`HeaderParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html), почитайте про них тоже.

Answer (score 0):

По пункту 3 немного не так. Вот отрывок из спецификации JAX-RS:

```java
@Path("smooth")
@GET
public Response smooth(
        @DefaultValue("2") @QueryParam("step") int step,
        ...
        ) { ... }
```

> If a query parameter "step" exists in the query component of the request URI, then the "step" value will be extracted and parsed as a 32–bit signed integer and assigned to the step method parameter. If "step" does not exist, then a default value of 2, as declared in the @DefaultValue annotation, will be assigned to the step method parameter. If the "step" value cannot be parsed as a 32–bit signed integer, then an HTTP 400 (Client Error) response is returned.

То есть, если параметр из URI нельзя привести к типу переменной, которой он присваивается, то будет возвращена ошибка HTTP 400.

Я такое съел на production и пока более опытный разработчик не ткнул меня носом, не мог понять, почему у меня REST-контроллер возвращает 400, а не JSON.