# Что такое Injection в JAX-RS?

Tags: java, java-ee, аннотации, jax-rs

Всем привет.

Наткнулся на данный код и объяснение из спеки 9 глава про `@Context` где   говорится про Injection, пришел к выводу что не могу понять идею "Injection" и по этому не понимаю для чего данная аннотация.

Injection переводится как "вставлять" "вводить", в java core я писал проект и создавал классы и на их основе объекты, в классах вводил данные в примитивные типы или типы определённого класса, передавал их другим классам и методам и вводил данные в базу данных. При переходе на ЕЕ появились аннотации и понятия "Иньекция" с которым не имел дело до этого.

```
@GET 
@Produces{"text/plain"} 
public String listQueryParamNames(@Context UriInfo info) 
{  
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(); 
for (String param: info.getQueryParameters().keySet())
{ 
buf.append(param);     buf.append("\n");  
} 
return buf.toString();
```

Есть понятные для меня аннотации как:

`@get @post @put @Delete @Path @PathParam @QueryParam`,но `@Context` сколько из того что я читал не могу понять, 
написано что она используется для "Injection" в Class field , или method, хотя это то что я делал и без этой аннотации до того как начал изучать EE.

1. "Injection" Не могу понять что это значить и что под этим подразумевается ?
2. Я привык писать параметры методов только с типом , при просмотре этого кода добавлена аннотация, для чего ? Что она добавляет в функционале или на что она влияет ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Внедрение, в значении [внедрения зависимостей (dependency injection, DI)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) - это, говоря простым языком, механизм подстановки значений полей или аргументов методов средой/выполнения/фреймворком/контейнером.

   Ваши JAX-RS-классы не выполняются в вакууме. Вы их даже не вызываете сами. Их вызывает фреймворк (Jersey/CXF/RESTEasy). Он и проводит внедрение значений перед вызовом метода.
2. Спецификация JAX-RS предполагает, что если в метод передается экземпляр какого-то класса без аннотаций - это тело HTTP-запроса (Request Body). Фреймворк попытается найти класс-провайдер, который умеет преобразовывать тело HTTP-запроса с конкретным `Content-Type` в объект вашего класса.

   Аннотация `@Context` сообщает фреймворку, что значение аргумента метода не надо пытаться получить из тела запроса, а подставить (внедрить) из другого места. Каких типов могут быть аргументы с аннотацией `@Context`, я описывал [в ответе на ваш предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522760/1984).

Comment: Какой то запутанный функционал к которому не как не могу привыкнуть.. Что то где то я не до понял и не могу понять ваш ответ..

Comment: Nofate - Есть ли у тебя ссылки на литературу/инфу в инете, которая поясняет эти процессы ? Твой ответ для меня на данном этапе как на китайском..

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html Книжки надо искать и не обязательно по жаве. В интернете мало статей на русском. А в книжках есть.

Comment: эмм.. ну так я понимаю тебя Сергей и да я заметил что мало на русском.. Остаётся вопрос какие книги ? Какой автор ? И если не обязательно по джаве то с удовольствием послушаю от вас про что мне искать..

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, для начала стоит освоиться до уверенного уровня в Java SE. Далее - ООП и паттерны у [Gang of Four](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) или хотя бы Head First Patterns. После этого с Java EE будет проще.

Comment: http://www.argc-argv.com/4_2011/article01.pdf похоже на перевод статьи мартина фолера, ссылку на которую приводил ранее

Comment: Nofate - Уровень уверенный спасибо. 
Вот нашел ссылку на простом языке про "Inversion Of Control" & Dependency Injection. 
http://www.apofig.com/2010/08/dependency-injection-inversion-of.html#cat

Comment: Nofate - "Фреймворк попытается найти класс-провайдер, который умеет преобразовывать тело HTTP-запроса с конкретным Content-Type в объект вашего класса."
 Можешь дать пример в коде для понимание этого процесса ?  
Не понятна данная строка из твоего ответа..:
"преобразовывать тело HTTP-запроса с конкретным Content-Type в объект вашего класса"

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, `@POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) void createRecord(Record rec) {}` - при вызове такого метода фреймворк попытается преобразовать тело HTTP-запроса в экземпляр класса `Record`. Если, например, тело представляет собой JSON {"data": "abc"}, а класс `Record` имеет поле `String data`, и все правильно настроено, то методу будет передан экземпляр `Record`, где поле `data="abc"`. В этом вся идея JAX-RS: работать с HTTP в удобной объектной модели и не задумываться о реализации HTTP-сервера.

Comment: Ок спасибо! понятно.

Comment: Сергей - Спасибо за ссылку на русском я почитаю.