# Как работает аннотация @Inject?

Tags: java, java-ee

Я новичок только учу `@Inject`. Я не очень понимаю, как он работает. Вот у меня есть поле:

`@Injection
private A a;`

И я могу использовать в своем коде a, хотя я не писал `new`. Правильно я понимаю, что `@Inject` просто объявляет `a = new A?` А что делать, если у меня класс `B` наследуется от `A` и я хочу сделать `a = new B;`?

И зачем так писать, почему не написать A a = new A(); ???

Спасибо все помогли

Появился еще вопрос Если аннотация лучше то мне теперь всегда в полях использовать аннотации вместо new?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523448/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-injection-%D0%B2-jax-rs

Comment: она не лучше, она решает ряд проблем, но не является золотой пулей

Comment: А какие недостатки..?

Comment: @Алексей дополнил свой ответ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Начнем по порядку

**Вопрос**: Правильно я понимаю, что `@Inject` просто объявляет `a = new A`?
**Ответ**: Не всегда. Все зависит от `scopa` для бина. Если scope выставлен как `prototype` то да, для каждого поля будет создаваться новый объект. Но как правило, например в `spring` значение по умолчанию это `singleton`. те создается один объект который затем присвается всем полям

**Вопрос**: А что делать, если у меня класс `B` наследуется от `A` и я хочу сделать `a = new B`?
**Ответ**: Ничего, с вашей стороны, никаких действий не требуется. DI фреймворки достаточны умны, чтобы обрабатывать подобные ситуации

**Вопрос**: И зачем так писать, почему не написать `A a = new A()`?
**Ответ**: Все это нужно для уменьшения связанности. Это позволяет более гибко изменять реализацию. Обычно, в роли А выступает какой нибудь интерфейс. И если в коде вы напишете `А а = new AImpl();` то в какой то момент, когда захотите поменять реализацию на `NewAImpl` вам потребуется везде изменять код. Это не удобно, если таких мест много. А если учитывать, что в каждом бине есть свои зависимости, то задача усложняется еще больше

Comment: "DI фреймворки достаточны умны, чтобы обрабатывать подобные ситуации"
А как "он" узнает что кому я хочу присвоить если у меня есть 3 реализации класса/интерфейса `А`?
Никогда об этом не задумывался, у меня всегда было по 1 реализации.

Comment: @AntonSorokin для этого есть доп аннотации или кастомные правила для инжектора

Comment: Если у вас есть несколько реализаций то вам нужно будет добавить классификатор - дополнительная аннотация, которая позволяет добиться однозначности

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Кстати. Вы пишите "то в какой то момент, когда захотите поменять реализацию на NewAImpl вам потребуется везде изменять код. Это не удобно, если таких мест много.". Т.е., предполагается что есть несколько реализаций и везде стоят квалификаторы(классификаторы?). Т.е., придется точно так же везде менять квалификаторы?

Comment: Ответьте пожалуйста на еще 1 вопрос я написал его вверху

Comment: Не совсем. Допустим у вас есть проект где везде используется класс A1 вы на него подвесили классификатор и он работает. Потом решили поменять его на А2, тогда просто убираете из конфигурационного файла либо из xml объявление бина А1 либо убираете у него классификатор и добавляете этот классифиактор в объявление бина А2

Answer (score 5):

Эта концепция называется [**Внедрение зависимостей**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) или `dependency injection`, в целом она позволяет получить более лаконичный код, уменьшить связность, и уменьшить возможные трудозатраты на поддержку кода в дальнейшем(задел на будущее).

Суть в следующем, есть объект-инжектор, при старте приложения Вы говорите ему:  создай мне экземпляр класса `A`, он создает его, затем при помощи reflection ищет все поля, помеченные аннотацией `@Inject` и создает их вышеописанным же образом.

Польза в этом следующая: при разработке отдельных модулей Вы можете не оперировать конкретными объектами, а писать интерфейсы и создавать их экземпляры, не зная при этом их фактической реализации. Например когда вы пишете `@Inject MyInterface foo;` при этом при конфигурации инжектора у вас указано что, мол, когда встретишь `MyInterface` создавай `MyImplementation.class`, то инжектор создаст класс `MyImplementation.class` и присвоит полю `foo` ссылку на него

Но и **недостатки** тоже есть - в некоторых ситуациях сложно будет писать юнит тесты, так же, вы можете узнать каким будет класс только в рантайме, т.е. если в проекте сложная логика, не всегда очевидно что в поле заинжектится, последнее затрудняет например навигацию в ide, и еще один немаловажный фактор - порог вхождения(иначе бы не пришлось Вам это здесь расписывать), т.е. если Вы втягиваете **DI** в свой проект, **новички** могут слегка просесть по началу, увидев его.

Comment: Cпасибо. Что такое за конфигурация? Это когда я создаю интерфейс с @Qualificator?

Comment: @Алексей это зависит от DI контейнера, в том которым пользуюсь я это вот - https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted тут второй блок кода public class BillingModule extends AbstractModule

Answer (score 3):

Суть в том, что какой именно из наследников будет в поле `private A a` определяет не тот класс, в котором это поле объявлено. Чтобы можно было подсунуть любую реализацию класса/интерфейса `A` извне. Т.е. если вы напишите `A a = new B();`  в каждом классе, в котором будет использоваться эта реализация `A`, то потом если вас попросят заменить на новый класс - например на новый наследник `C implements A` то вам придется руками это исправлять в каждом классе. А если речь идет о сотнях классов, то это будет тяжело